# What can I use as a temporary noise insulation on a door that connects bedroom and bathroom?

Tags: insulation, noise

our bathroom has 2 doors and we only use one. The other one remains shut and it connects to a bedroom. We do not intend on ever opening it (but we are renting the place so we need something that eventually we could remove easily).

Is there anything we could add to that connecting door to reduce bathroom noise?

Comment: You could put a bookcase, big blanket, huge mirror, whatever in front of the door.  If you are never using it you can remove the handle on the one side so whatever you put there is flat.

Comment: If you weren't renting, I would recommend replacing the door with a good quality solid core door. They probably built that place with the cheapest materials available.

Answer (score -1):

Fill the cracks around the door, especially at the bottom with [egg crate foam](https://www.google.com/shopping/product/15021887706624945254?q=egg+crate+foam+sound+absorbing). Cut it up and pack it in. Preventing air movement will help a lot with preventing sound transfer.

An alt to the foam is [weather stripping](http://www.homedepot.com/b/Tools-Hardware-Hardware-Weather-Stripping-Door-Seals/N-5yc1vZc3dy?browsestoreoption=2). This would be a more permanent solution that will allow for the door to be used and still help to deaden the sound. Something that would would have to bug your landlord about before doing it.

Once that is done putting something solid in front of the door on the other side like a bookcase or decorative rug will help even more. If you can hang towels on the bathroom side as well that will help a little bit.